# What was Draco Malfoy's Patronus?

Tags: harry-potter, patronus-charm

Had he been able to produce one, would it have been a ferret? Since it appears that a person's Patronus takes on the same form as their Animagus. I realize that a ferret might not have been Draco's Animagus form but rather Moody's choice of animal in GoF, but are there any mentions of what form Draco's Patronus could have taken?

Comment: Draco isn't an Animagus.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Per JK Rowling's original website, it's not known.

> **Q. What is Draco Malfoy’s Patronus?**
>
> **JKR:** *As of the end of Half-Blood Prince, **he has no idea how to produce one,
> so nobody knows.** You must remember that the ability to produce a
> Patronus demonstrates an advanced level of magic not routinely taught
> to young Hogwarts students (hence the surprise of the prospective
> members of Dumbledore’s Army when they find out that Harry can make a
> Patronus).*
>
> <sub><sup>[J.K.Rowling Official Site - FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20070607000130/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/faq_view.cfm?id=118)</sup></sub>

Given his lack of need to produce a Patronus charm (it's very specialised and not especially useful) and the fact that his formal education ended shortly afterwards, it seems likely that he simply never learned to form a corporeal Patronus. Any speculation on the matter is simply that.